# Comparar dois numeros e pegar o maior

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá pessoal estou criando este [script](https://jsfiddle.net/2hcL226r/) para verificar o maior numero e aplica-lo como desconto, mas estou com problemas para identificar o numero maior e fazer o calculo.

A duvida é como pegar os valores com a vírgula e retornar o maior valor.

```js
$('.item').each(function() {
 var item = $(this);
 var flag = item.find('.flag');
 var value;
 
    //ESTE IF VERIFICA SE TEM MAIS DE 1 FLAG 
    //QUERO RETORNAR O NUMERO MAIOR COM PONTO OU VIRGULA ENTRE AS 2 FLAGS
 if(flag.length > 1){
        flag.each(function() {
            value = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            console.log(value);
        });
    };
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;font-family:sans-serif;box-sizing:border-box}
ul{display:flex;justify-content:space-around}
.item{padding:10px;width:30%;float:left;border:1px solid #000}
.flag,.console-log{margin:5px 0;padding:5px 0;color:#FFF;text-align:center;background-color:#1485D3}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="item">
        <p class="flag 1897----promo-comprador">18,97% - Promo Comprador</p>
        <p class="flag 8131----desconto-no-boleto">8,131% - Desconto no Boleto</p>
        <p id="" class="console-log"></p>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
        <p class="flag 1897----promo-comprador">18,97% - Promo Comprador</p>
        <p class="flag 8131----desconto-no-boleto">8,131% - Desconto no Boleto</p>
        <p id="" class="console-log"></p>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
        <p class="flag 1897----promo-comprador">18,97% - Promo Comprador</p>
        <p class="flag 8131----desconto-no-boleto">8,131% - Desconto no Boleto</p>
        <p id="" class="console-log"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Você tem acesso ao HTML a ponto de poder alterá-lo? Se sim, faz mais sentido você adiicionar um atributo nas tags `p`: `<p data-percentual="18.97">...</p>`

Comment: @Uilque Messias Não tenho acesso, isso é gerado de um sistema então tenho que trabalhar com isso mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

você terá de incluir <kbd>.</kbd> e <kbd>,</kbd> a sua expressão regular, então transformar a sua string para um decimal valido.

```js
// lista de textos que contem um valor decimal.
var textos = [
  "18,97% - Promo Comprador",
  "8,131% - Desconto no Boleto"
];

// extraindo os valores com ponto flutuante dos textos.
var valores = textos.map(function (texto, indice) {
  return texto.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '').replace(",", ".");
});

// obtendo o maior valor dentro do array.
var maior = Math.max(...valores);

console.log(maior);
```

Comment: Você pode usar `Math.max.apply` para fazer a comparação dos maiores números.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai, obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: @TobyMost Nossa! Eu não sabia que existia `...` dentro da expressão de argumentos em JavaScript... você sabe qual é o nome desses 3 pontos?

Comment: @KlaiderKlai, também não sabia o nome do mesmo, mas ja que perguntou, encontrei eles em uma pesquisa rapida.: [operador spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: @hydroper eu tbm não sabia que existia no JS isso... sempre optava por fazer uma grande linha de código pra percorrer todos valores (Vivendo e aprendendo realmente...)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode mudar a `regex` para facilitar a busca e depois trocar o `,` por `.` (pois o método `parseFloat` funciona no padrão *en-US*):

```js
$('.item').each(function() {
    var greaterValue = -99999, greaterFlag = null;
 
    $(this).find('.flag').each(function() {
        var textValue = $(this).text().replace(/^([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)\%.*$/, '$1.$2');
        var numericValue = parseFloat(textValue);

        if(!isNaN(numericValue) && numericValue > greaterValue) {
            greaterValue = numericValue;
            greaterFlag = $(this); // pega a tag <p/> atual
        }
    });

    console.log('greater value: ' + greaterValue + ' | greater flag tag: ' + greaterFlag.text());
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;font-family:sans-serif;box-sizing:border-box}
ul{display:flex;justify-content:space-around}
.item{padding:10px;width:30%;float:left;border:1px solid #000}
.flag,.console-log{margin:5px 0;padding:5px 0;color:#FFF;text-align:center;background-color:#1485D3}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="item">
        <p class="flag 1897----promo-comprador">18,97% - Promo 1 Comprador</p>
        <p class="flag 8131----desconto-no-boleto">8,131% - Desconto 1 no Boleto</p>
        <p id="" class="console-log"></p>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
        <p class="flag 1897----promo-comprador">1,24% - Promo 2 Comprador</p>
        <p class="flag 8131----desconto-no-boleto">89,131% - Desconto 2 no Boleto</p>
        <p id="" class="console-log"></p>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
        <p class="flag 1897----promo-comprador">11,9737% - Promo 3 Comprador</p>
        <p class="flag 8131----desconto-no-boleto">2,00% - Desconto 3 no Boleto</p>
        <p id="" class="console-log"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.max.apply` para fazer a comparação dos números. Para resolver a comparação, tente se basear nesse código especifíco:

```
$('.item').each(function() {

    var item = $(this);
    var flag = item.find('.flag');

    /* Array com números das flags do item */
    var numbers = [];

    /* Percorre sobre cada flag */
    flag.each(function(f) {

        // Tira o número da flag da string e adiciona para a array;
        numbers.push(
            parseFloat($(f).text().replace('.', ','))
        );

    });

    // Pega o número máximo na array
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers);

    // Loga o número máximo no console do navegador
    console.log(max);

});
```